# ?? Combine, join, insert in query Access 2007-2010?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables that I would like to make into one table.

TABLE WASP_COLOR1

```
ID    NAME    COLOR    CODE     
1    WASP01    RED      RD  
2    WASP04    RED      RD  
3    WASP19    BLUE     BL
```

TABLE WASP_COLOR2

```
ID   NAME     SIZE     CODE     
1    WASP01     6       RD   
2    WASP13    10       BL  
3    WASP22     4       BL
```

I'm a novice and I need clear direction on how to obtain these results. (I want the duplicates merged.)

TABLE WASP_COLOR1

```
ID   NAME     COLOR    SIZE    CODE     
1    WASP01    RED       6      RD     
2    WASP04    RED              RD     
3    WASP19    BLUE             BL     
4    WASP13             10      BL     
5    WASP22              4      BL
```

I tried the following:

```
SELECT 
  distinct wasp_color2.name, wasp_color2.size, 
  wasp_color2.code, wasp_color1.name, wasp_color1.color, 
  wasp_color1.code 
INTO 
  wasp_color1
FROM 
  wasp_color2, wasp_color1;
```

Received error

I tried:

```
SELECT 
  distinct wasp_color2.name, wasp_color2.size, wasp_color2.code, 
  wasp_color1.name, wasp_color1.color, wasp_color1.code 
INTO 
  test
FROM 
  wasp_color2, wasp_color1;
```

Received 9 rows instead of 5

I tried:

```
SELECT 
  name.wasp_color1, name.wasp_color2, color, size, 
  code.wasp_color1, code.wasp_color2  
INTO 
  test
FROM wasp_color2, wasp_color1;
```

This asks for a parameter value, which is a manual entry and cumbersome

I tried:

```
SELECT 
  coalesce name.wasp_color1, name.wasp_color2, color, 
  size, code.wasp_color1, code.wasp_color2  
INTO 
  test
FROM 
  wasp_color2, wasp_color1 full join;
```

Received error

Comment: In normal SQL you'd use a FULL OUTER JOIN,  Access doesn't support those so you'll have to use a LEFT join, right join and a union

Comment: thanks for responding so quickly!  I'm not sure what the "wc1" and the "wc2" is in the following statement?                                                     FROM wasp_Color1 wc1                                                                       LEFT JOIN wasp_color2 wc2

Comment: those are table aliases.  instead of typing out WASP_COLOR1  or wasp_color2 everytime I tell the database engine to use WC1 instead.  It makes it easier to read and less to type.  You can alias tables and columns this way

Comment: thanks for the clarification and your script worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this as MS access doesn't support full outer joins.

What this does is generate two data sets one for wasp_Color1 and those records that match in wasp_Color2 and vice-versa.  and then combine's those results into one data set eliminating the duplicates.

For a better understanding of joins: see https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

```
Select WC1.Name, WC1.Color, WC2.Size, WC1.Code
FROM wasp_Color1 wc1
LEFT JOIN wasp_color2 wc2
 on wc1.Name = WC2.Name
and wc1.code = wc2.code

UNION

Select WC2.Name, WC1.Color, WC2.Size, WC2.Code
FROM wasp_Color1 wc1
RIGHT JOIN wasp_color2 wc2
 on wc1.Name = WC2.Name
and wc1.code = wc2.code
```